# Toolkit2d anchors Unity3d touchscreen predetermined area

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

It is necessary to make the touch screen is only recorded in a predetermined area. If you do it via conventional Unity, then just do two vectors (bottom left and top right) and check the touch, whether we enter into this area. But I would like to make with the help of anchors from Toolkit2d. How to make this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply! Create an anchor on the camera, such as the upper left and lower right, attach it to the game objects, further the position of these objects use to create a rectangular area. When scaling anchors pull over an area and it is displayed correctly with different resolutions.

```
private Rect area;
public GameObject upLeft;
public GameObject downRight;
area = new Rect(upLeft.transform.position.x, downRight.transform.position.y,
        downRight.transform.position.x - upLeft.transform.position.x, upLeft.transform.position.y - downRight.transform.position.y);
 if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && area.Contains(Input.mousePosition))
    {//same code}
```